# The dimension of binary linear codes

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

I am following the book Essential Coding Theory, by professor Madhu Sudan. It is freely available in the following link: https://cse.buffalo.edu/faculty/atri/courses/coding-theory/book/

In page 49, a comment in bracket puzzled me. It states the dimension of a binary linear code $C_{H,r}$ is

$$k = n - O(\log _2 n)$$

I do not understand why.
I tried to prove it using the following path:

By definition:

$$k = \log _q |C|$$

Since we have binary code, $q=2$. Then, to reach the desired equality above, linearity should allow me to reach the following equality:
$$|C| = \frac{2^n}{O(n)}$$

I fail to understand how linearity gives me this.

More directions:

- I know that for general codes, $|C| \le 2^n$.
- From linearity, I know that $C$ is the nullspace of $H$, where $H$ is the parity check matrix. Thus, $C = \{c \in \ \mathbb{F}_{q}^n | Hc = 0\}$. This means that $|C| = dim(\text{ker}(H))$. Considering Linear Algebra, I know that $dim(\text{V})=n$, and that $dim(\text{ker}(H)) = dim(V) - dim(\text{im}(H))$. But what is $\text{im}(H)$ ? And how does this direction lead me into something with $\log_2 n$, or, alternatively, a ratio of the form $\frac{2^n}{O(n)}$?

---

Edit: Thank you for answering my question. Associating linear codes with linear spaces confused me because of the notational overhead from associating codewords with vectors (and codes with matrices).

Comment: As Henno already replied, in the book, p. 46, by definition, $C_{H, r}$ is the $[n = 2^r - 1, k = 2^r - r - 1, 3]_2$ Hamming code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler than you think.

In the Hamming code for word length $n=2^r - 1$ which has dimension $2^r - r -1= n -r$ just note that $r = O(\log_2(n))$ (by the definition of $\log_2$) so that indeed the dimension equals $n-r = n - O(\log_2(n))$ as claimed. Nothing fancy.

Comment: Thank you! I found out that introducing linear codes as linear subspaces caused me a notational headache. By the way, your explanation is written in page 50. It is annoying that stuff written in page x are based on stuff written in page y when x<y.

Comment: Those are lecture notes for a postgraduate course, not a finished textbook. Lecture notes by Jonathan Hall available online are much better for a beginner.